is there a way to log down the command line strings inside a tcl script file after sourcing it
I have to source a tcl script file in my c++ codes, like:
std::string cmd = "source test.tcl";
Tcl_Eval(cmd.c_str());

there are lots of procs/commands in this script file and var/command subst will happen after invoking, i wonder how to use tcl C APIs to log down every specific command after subst has been done or is there a way of restoring the original command string just inside a c++ function that is registered as the proc of self defined tcl command? thanks.

It is not at all clear what you are asking.

A command execution trace can do it (see trace add execution, or Tcl_TraceCommand with the right options,  notably TCL_TRACE_ENTER_DURING_EXEC). You need a wrapper command to apply the tracing context to, but that could be just this triviality:
proc trace_wrapper script {
    uplevel 1 $script
}

Note that the Tcl API mentioned above is a wrapper around the C API; neither is more powerful than the other.

Note that tracing commands has a profound performance impact! It tends to inhibit bytecode compilation...
